# Textmate 2 - Delete a Macro

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I was not able to find a way to delete a custom macro that I just created using the latest Textmate version. Surely this should be fairly simple task?

The only option in the Edit Bundle section is the enable/disable the macro.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the macro in the bundle, and either use the hotkey (Command + Delete) or the menu; [image: Edit - Delete]

If for some reason that doesn't work, the macros themselves are stored in

`~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles/[BUNDLE NAME].tmBundle/Commands`

or

`~/Library/Application Support/Textmate/Bundles/[BUNDLE NAME].tmBundle/Commands`

And you can just delete the files from there.